# char* comparison against value set in previous instruction not optimized away?

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

While fiddling with some test code, I observed that in the following code:

```
extern char* pc;
int muysimple() {
  *pc = 0;
  if (*pc != 0) { return 1111; }

  return 4444;
}
```

the comparison is *not* optimized away by any compiler I can select on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/4cMSiE).

If I change the `extern char*` to an `extern int*`, the comparison *will* be optimized away.

Why would gcc and clang both keep the comparison for `char`, even though there seems to be nothing in this code that could legally change the value so that the comparison ever evaluates to true?

**Is there anything in the language spec that inhibits this optimization for the write/read through `char*`** (but *allows* the optimization for `int*`!) or are the optimizers just more conservative around char?

---

As it was already mentioned in commets: I don't see -- *rule wise* -- how aliasing rules could come into play here. There's only one variable visible to this code and no multithreading or call to anywhere.

Of course, the `char` aliasing rule(s) may very well be the practical reason compilers do not optimize this, but the question here is whether the compilers **would** be allowed to optimize this for `char*` -- as they do for `int*` -- or whether they are actually not allowed to optimize this.

Comment: `extern int` or `extern int*`?

Comment: Godbolt gives the same behavior if you remove the `extern`.  This looks like you are getting hit by UB.  `*pc = 0;` is UB since the pointer is never initialized.

Comment: @KirillKobelev - "Is there an actual language-rule that inhibits the optimization" - that is the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver - what UB? It's `extern`, it isn't initialized in this transaltion unit.

Comment: @imreal - fixed text. pointers in both cases.

Comment: @MartinBa, do you know **any** language rule that controls/inhibits optimization (except for volatile, that is largely remnant of the dark ages)?

Comment: @KirillKobelev Perhaps not a language rule per se, but for example aliasing pointers prevent optimizations. I guess the question is if anything is going on with char pointers that can prevent an optimization in this case.

Comment: Yes... A `char*` can alias anything, but `int*` can't. But here the compiler could see that nothing happens between setting 0 and reading, so it could optimize it.

Comment: @MartinBa Looks like the optimization does work with a char array of size 1, in which case a char pointer is also dereferenced. https://godbolt.org/g/aItKuT

Comment: @Danra - see my edit. (your exmpl: nice catch. In the array case no aliasing is possible (because it refers to an actual char object) whereas in the char* case aliasing comes into play *in principle* (though shouldn't actually matter IMHO.)

Comment: A compiler is allowed to optimize anything - as long as the observable behavior of the program does not change. (see the "as-if rule")

Comment: @MartinBa With the `-fno-strict-aliasing flag`, int* doesn't optimize either, probably since the compiler can't assume it doesn't alias other memory. https://godbolt.org/g/s62KTK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> even though there seems to be nothing in this code that could legally change the value so that the comparison ever evaluates to true?

`pc = (char *) &pc;` is a valid assignment, and since `char` lvalues may be used to access any POD type, the assignment to `*pc` may change `pc`.

Comment: Wow - didn't think about that. (But can it ever be legal to overwrite one byte of an address, and then dereference it?)

Comment: @alain It's far-fetched, but consider a custom `memcpy`-like function which already checked that all the other bytes already have the desired values.

Comment: Make that `pc = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&pc));` because C-style casts really muddle up things. Otherwise seems a very good catch to me.

Comment: Great catch! :) And also explains why with other pointer types, the code does get optimized, *unless* strict aliasing is turned off.

Comment: @MartinBa I am not immediately sure if that is the right way, or if it should be a `reinterpret_cast`, or if it does not matter. Either way, this C-style cast is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: This is an example of why the C89 rules should have been deprecated long ago as a horrible kludge: they block useful optimizations, while inviting code-breaking "optimizations".  The appearance of typecasts between uses of different pointer types should be a stronger indication of aliasing than the fact that one of the types in question is a character type, but the C Standard focuses only on the latter.

Comment: @supercat At the same time, the freedom for both the standard library and custom containers to check for trivially copyable types, and use `memcpy` instead of element-by-element copying, is a very useful optimisation as well.

Comment: @hvd: Code which uses `memcpy` generally converts the pointers to character types *after* the last preceding use of the objects as their original types, and all uses of pointers derived from the cast will be competed *before* the next use of the objects as their original types, so most programs wouldn't have needed the "character type exception" to make code using `memcpy` work if the common cast-use-abandon sequence were supported for all types, and the optimizations foregone by supporting the latter construct would in most cases be less severe than those lost to the character-type rule.

Comment: @hvd: The rule that would be needed for most optimizations would say that if an object is accessed twice, and a compiler has no reason to expect that anything else may have accessed it in the interim, the accesses may be considered unsequenced with regard to anything that happens between them.  Defining things in those terms, and then specifying what actions should make a compiler expect that an object might have been accessed, would allow more real optimizations and fewer phony ones, than the present rules.

Comment: @supercat Even in that case, the character type exception is needed to let the code be valid. There's nothing else in the standard that would allow such aliasing. A different, stricter, rule might be sufficient, but simply deprecating it entirely is too much. (Note: this was in response only to the first of your previous two comments.)

Comment: @hvd: The present Standard fails to allow for the common cast-use-abandon pattern, but if the Standard *did* allow for such a pattern, I fail to see why that would be insufficient to accommodate the vast majority of the use cases for memcpy.  The rules for `void*` would need to be slightly more complicated, but not outrageously so (say that if a pointer knows the type from which a `void*` was converted, it may treat the `void*` as though it were that type, but otherwise `void*` is--for purposes of aliasing--"pointer to anything").

Comment: @hvd: Deprecating a construct would recognize it as being valid while encouraging the use of alternatives and preparing for the possibility that while compilers wishing to be compatible with today's code will need to be able to support it, it may not always be a default mode.  I'd consider that a fair sight better than C99's treatment of `memcpy` which breaks existing code without providing any workaround nor even acknowledging that anything had changed (and to top it off, provides relatively few actual optimization opportunities compared with what a better rule would have done).

Comment: Hm, "`pc = (char*)&pc;` is a valid assignment" - what does it mean valid? Is there any grounds for this validity in the standard itself? Can you give any reference? Is `pint = (int*)&pint;` also valid?

Comment: @KirillKobelev "Valid" just means there's nothing disallowing such an assignment. I'm not going to quote each and every sentence of the standard to explain why that particular sentence doesn't disallow it. As for `pint = (int*)&pint;`, whether the assignment itself is valid is more complicated (it depends on alignment, which is platform-specific), but it's not relevant here. Even when that assignment is valid, it doesn't make `*pint` a `char` lvalue, so the rest of my answer still doesn't apply.

Comment: @phd, There is no need to quote irrelevant pieces of the standard. What place  makes `char*` special?

Comment: @KirillKobelev I do not know how to answer that because I cannot tell from your question which part you're stuck on. There's two aspects. One is, is the assignment `pi = (int*)&pi;` valid? Two is, is it then allowed to change `*pi` so that `pi`'s value changes? You appear to be asking about the first, but it's the second where `char` is special. For the first, for most systems, it would be valid even for `int`. For the second, not so. I didn't cite the standard for the second because the OP already well aware of that and referenced the same rule in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `char*` being allowed to alias *anything* includes `volatile` memory.

With the `-fpermissive` flag, `gcc` just gives a warning about a `char*` pointing to volatile memory, but [compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/hkTmCg).

Since in your example the pointer is `extern`, it's possible another translation compiled with this flag, so the pointer points to `volatile` memory. Hence no optimization can be made.

I didn't find an official reference to whether a non-volatile `char*` aliasing `volatile` memory is considered legal or UB.

EDIT:
Looks like the same warning is given for assignment of `int*` to `volatile int*`, in which case the compiler does do the optimization. So I guess the warning/permissive flags aren't related. The question is just whether or not `char*` is allowed in general to alias `volatile` memory in general.

Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/g/R2EqIu) of "cleverly" aliasing a `volatile` `struct` using C++ casts only with no warnings.

EDIT2: Looks like adding the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag causes *any* pointer type to not optimize in the original code. Therefore, I guess the reason the compilers don't optimize when they're wary of aliasing. Either because:

1. Aliasing `volatile` memory is allowed (?)
2. Fear of data races with other pointers to the same non-volatile memory. @alain mentions in his answer that data races are UB, but even if that's true, I guess the compiler makers decided to be careful here, and not to optimize.

Comment: From a languange POV, since I'm *not* allowed to assign `volatile char*` to `char*`, I guess a "normal" `char*` cannot alias volatile objects -- but note the "guess" :-)

Comment: Fixed the Godbolt link to display the warning.

Comment: I think `volatile` is treated like `const` - What matters is the pointer/reference used to access the object, not how the object was initially declared. For example you can't modify an `int` if you use a `const int*`.

Comment: @alain Sure, though I'm not certain whether or not *actually* aliasing volatile memory with a non volatile char* (or any pointer in case of -fno-strict-aliasing) is considered UB or not.